# uploading big file in codeigniter displays 403 error page instead of returning upload error

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $config['upload_path']          = './private/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|mp4';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Note: working on localhost only

1. i tried to upload less than <= 1mb and its a success = GOOD
2. i tried to upload 2mb to 3mb = error (The file you are attempting to upload is larger than the permitted size.) = GOOD

but when i tried to upload 1gb video file (for testing purposes)

it throws 403 forbidden page, instead of throwing upload error like in no. 2

Comment: note: (for testing purposes), see above

i know that i need to change the php.ini but i think php.ini will be the second problem. 

the main point is, its throwing 403 than 5xx error means (server error)

Answer (score 0):

why there is dot in './private/'

```
$config['upload_path'] = '/private/';
```

**Try this,**

```
$config['max_size'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

```
upload_max_filesize = your-value
```

Must be greater than or equal to `upload_max_filesize`

```
post_max_size = your-value
```

After modifying the php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use the new configuration.

[Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)